# using spring + hibernate mvc

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image]

I have started Web Application using Spring + Hibernate MVC. I Created All File. There are some issues when i'm debug my application.
Here I have attached code for web.xml, test-servlet.xml  and I added error line 
any one help me plz on this???

> error : org.springframework.beans.factory.beandefinitionstoreexception
>   unexpected exception parsing xml document from file
>   /WEBINF/config/test.servlet.xml

**test-servlet**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

  <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>model.Register</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

[image: test-servlet]

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0">

  <display-name>SpringHibernateMVC</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

[image: web.xml]

Comment: show us the error message

Comment: The stacktrace was included in the linked image. I fixed the formatting a bit..

Comment: Any reason why you reverted my edit?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace as text not as an image it is unreadable that way and not the whole trace is visible.

Answer (score 0):

From the project folder image i could see that you are missing resource folder.

Please ensure that you have resources/database.properties file which you have mentioned in 
test.servlet.xml.

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
```